# Equation , powers of two

Tags: elementary-functions

I want to find the sum of the roots of the equation $$4(4^x + 4^{-x}) - 23(2^x + 2^{-x}) + 40 = 0  $$ in real numbers. I tried the substitution $ 2^x = t $ but then it turns into a quartic equation which I couldn't solve. I think its roots sum to zero so I want to prove it without actually finding the roots.

Comment: $$(2^x+2^{-x})^2=4^x+2+4^{-x}$$ may help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is a root of this equation, then $-x$ is too. Thus, the sum of the roots is $0$.

Comment: Your argument assumes that there is at least one solution.

Comment: @gammatester: Nope. If there are no roots, the sum of no roots is still $0$. (While we're at it, if $0$ is a root, $-0$ isn't a separate root, but the contribution to the sum is still $0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $2^x+2^{-x}=t$. Then $4(t^2-2)-23t+40=0 \implies 4t^2-23t+32=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$4\left(a^2+\frac1{a^2}\right)-23\left(a+\frac1a\right)+40=0$$

$$\implies 4\left[\left(a+\frac1a\right)^2-2\right]-23\left(a+\frac1a\right)+40=0$$

$\displaystyle a+\frac1a=b\implies 4(b^2-2)-23b+40=0\iff 4b^2-23b+32=0$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if $\exists{r}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=r$ is a solution, then $x=-r$ is also a solution.

So the sum of the roots of the equation (if there are any) is obviously $0$.

Second, here is a full analysis of your equation (from [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%284%5Ex%2b4%5E%28%E2%88%92x%29%29%E2%88%9223%282%5Ex%2b2%5E%28%E2%88%92x%29%29%2b40=0)):

[image]